# Google Analytics - Goal - refreshing the final page means another goal hit?

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking, goals

I have a Goal set up with four steps and a destination, and Step1 is Required? YES.

If I go through the journey I register and goal hit once I get to the final page.
However if I hit the browser's Refresh button, it counts as another goal hit (Reporting -> Conversions -> Goal Hits (Last 30 min)).

This can't be correct surely? What could be wrong with my analytics setup that reloading the "Thanks" page screws up my metrics so badly?

Comment: Can you include a screenshot for your goal config. The second goal shouldn't be counted because only one conversion per session is accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @nyuen mentioned, only one conversion per session is accepted, however the realtime view will report goal hits, not conversions. Refreshing the page will cause the goal to be hit again, increasing the `goal hits` metric.

When the data is processed (i.e. a few hours later in the regular conversions report) you should only see one goal conversion. The confusion here is because of the different metric labels (i.e. `goal hit` vs. `goalXcompletion`).